# the next text of the selecetedtext in combobox in c#?

Tags: c#, text, combobox

it is a program about school in c#
I have comboboxGrade it is data bound the texts in it are grades names, and after selecting a text comboboxGrade.Text which is a grade name I do some coding but after that when determining the student stat is "pass" I need to put in a string variable the next text of the current text i.e.
after selecting a grade visually from the form the text will be combobox.Text == "fourth"
but I need in the code to get to the next text which is fifth when student pass, How?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do that.
One just using the combo is

```
if ((combobox.SelectedIndex >= 0) && ((combobox.SelectedIndex + 1) < combobox.Items.Count))
{
   String nextGrade = combobox.Items[combobox.SelectedIndex + 1].ToString();
}
```

I'd be doing something similar off the data the combobox is bound to though.